# How to create a Record (histroy __C -custom object) with old Values and New Values(Account) after update trigger

Tags: trigger

Example: if Record Is inserted or updated, i need create record with Old Vales and new Values in histroy __C custom object how to do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**added based on comments**

As you need to create records in custom object based on Account record changes, lets consider custom object AccountHistory__c with corresponding fields `Account__c, NewName__c, OldName__c` and other such fields. As you need to create different object, you should use after trigger. Below will be sample trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update, after update) {

    List<AccountHistory__c> accHisList = new List<AccountHistory__c>();

    if(Trigger.operationType==System.TriggerOperation.AFTER_UPDATE) { // After trigger context
        Map<Id, Account> oldValues = Trigger.oldMap;
        for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
            accHisList.add(new AccountHistory__c(
                Account__c = acc.Id, 
                NewName__c = acc.Name,
                OldName__c = oldValues.get(acc.Id).Name
            ));
        }
    }

    if(!accHisList.isEmpty())
        insert accHisList;
}
```

---

You do not need new custom object to track the record changes. For many Standard and all Custom Objects, you can track records history. If its standard object then you should check if [Field History Tracking is available](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=5).

First, you need to check how to [Track Field History for Standard Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&type=5) and [Track Field History for Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&type=5).

If its standard object, you can get the history from `ObjectHistory` object. For example, for Account you can use below SOQL for history:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM AccountHistory
```

Use AccountId filter for checking the record changes for particular record.

And for custom object you will have `CustomObject__History` object. Below is the exmaple SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM CustomObject__History
```

Here, `ParentId` can be filtered if you need to check record changes in a particular record.

Comment: ya Inkow That  but my scenario is After Update Record in Accounts Create a Record with old Vales And update values in history object LIke: Industry: OldVAlue-banking  newvalue- Entertainment like By Using triger

Comment: I think this is a typical [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I cannot understand Your comment, can you please put it as detailed as possible in question.

Comment: let assume  we have Account Object . when a Record updated . create a Record with Account  old Values And New Values  in a custom object.

Comment: Tha custom object contains Some fields Like Account Old Name , New Name ,Old Industry Value,and New Industry value

Comment: added in answer

Answer (score -1):

You can only use old values in update trigger. You can use it by using trigger.old and feed the trigger.old values to the record you want to create (history__c record). For the new records you can use trigger.new and feed its values to the record you want to create.

Comment: can u share any reference code

Comment: lol can u read again. I said he can only use old values in update triggers but i didnt say he cant use new values. thanks for the -1

Comment: you miss understood my sentence. please read and understand my whole answer. thanks.

Comment: @TejaMani you can use this as reference. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers